# Windows 11 sign out automatically after login

Tags: windows, login, windows-11

I am having a bit problem with Windows 11, Whenever I am logging in, it signs out me automatically after a few seconds of login. It is not in the loop, I mean it is not happening every time I login. It is happening one or two times after booting the system, then everything goes normal.

Few points to note

1. This is not a fresh installation. I upgraded from windows 10.
2. First I faced this issue in the 22000.282 build, currently on the dev channel, using 22494.1000 build
3. I don't use any third-party driver software, rather than Microsoft update & recommended Optional Updates

Comment: I am not seeing this on Windows 11 Pro Production (new) or Windows 11 Pro Insider (since July).  Have you checked and reset your power driver and settings including shutdown and lid settings (if applicable)

Comment: My brother-in-law had this same problem. He was not actually able to access his desktop when logging in (would immediately log him out -- every time). He is now happily using Ubuntu.

Comment: @John I checked. It seems this is not a power plan/settings-related issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt. Ya man I was also using Linux Mint as my daily driver at some point, but since my office/organization uses Windows & workflow moves around Windows architecture, I also moved back to Windows again. Monopoly Wins